# What is the controlled variable in this particular case?

Tags: control, feedback, system, closed-loop

I have a question, maybe you can help me because I am not sure of the correct definition.
As an example I have a plant with a measured output y in a closed loop system. But as the feedback variable I use y' = y + 100 to substract this from the setpoint.
Does the calculation of y' belong to the plant and is y' the controlled variable then?
Or is y the actual controlled variable and how is y' then called?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: y is your output, 100 is what ? y' just has offset to match input? . What is your input called ?

Comment: I want to control a variable that cannot be measured directly from the plant. But this variable y' can be approximated by the output y of the plant, in this case for example by y' = y + 100. The example does not relate to a real situation but I was just wondering what the acutal controlled variable would be in this case.

Comment: It all depends on  details but your transfer function is what y/x? and 100 is just an offset to reduce error effects of DC gain

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a state-space representation of your **plant** as follows:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=Ax+Bu\\
y=Cx+Du\\
z\approx y+100
\end{cases}
$$
These are usual signal names you would find:

- \$x\$: plant states
- \$u\$: plant input / control signal
- \$y\$: plant output / measurable output
- \$z\$: controlled output / non-measurable output

In order to compose the feedback control loop, you are taking the plant output through an **estimator** system:
$$
\hat{z}=y+100
$$

- \$\hat{z}\$: estimation of controlled output

I avoided using your \$y'\$ notation, since I think it's misleading for the explanation, but it should be equivalent as the \$z\$ or \$\hat{z}\$ signals in this notation.